# Problems linking view and controller

Tags: php, laravel, view, laravel-4, controller

This is the error I am getting on the sample view:

```
Undefined variable: sampleRecord
```

This is the controller code:

```
 public function show($sample_id)
 {
    return View::make('samples.show')->with([
        $this->sampleRepository->find($sample_id),
        $this->sampleRecord->getSamplePartNumberRecord,
    ]);
 }
```

This is the view code:

```
<p>{{ $sampleRecord }}</p>

@foreach($sampleRecord->SamplePartNumbers() as $samplePartNumberRecord)
<p>Sample Part Number: <br />{{ $samplePartNumberRecord }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: maybe try `$this->sampleRecord`?

Comment: Maybe would be nice to tell us, which MVC framework do you use so we don't have to guess a solution.

Comment: Oh I am sorry Laravel

Comment: First key is the variable to pass to the view `with('variableName' => 'Datas');`

Comment: Can you post the code for all models involved so we can see your relationships? Is `sampleRecord` a relationship of `$this` or `sampleRepository`?  It seems logical that a `sampleRepository` would have a/many `sampleRecord`. also is `getSamplePartNumberRecord` a property or method? If it's a method, it should be `getSamplePartNumberRecord()`

Answer (score 4):

your controller should be:

```
public function show($sample_id)
{
    return View::make('samples.show')->with([
        "sampleRepository" => $this->sampleRepository->find($sample_id),
        "sampleRecord" => $this->sampleRecord->getSamplePartNumberRecord,
    ]);
 }
```

Comment: That change causes this error now Call to a member function SamplePartNumbers() on a non-object

Comment: @CameronWinter `$sampleRecord` is `null` on your view.

Comment: +1. For me problem is solved. You have another problem in your script. Btw, Ben gives you the answer.

Comment: SO how do I fix that?