# Trouble with view and controller using eloquent models

Tags: php, laravel, view, controller

I am using two eloquent models alpha and beta.  I am having trouble with the controller and the view.  Alpha is designed to have multiple betas and their is a hasMany relationship established.  When redirected to the show page they should see the alpha and the beta data by alpha_id.  The code I am currently using is pulling an error and after looking in the book and online I can not figure out how to fix it.

Here is the controller code:

```
public function display($alpha_id)
{
    return View::make('alpha.show')->with([
        'alpha' => $this->alphaRepository->findBy($alpha_id),
        $alpha->alphaRecord->getBeta(),
    ]);
}
```

Here is the view:

```
<p>{{ $alpha }}</p>

@foreach($alpha->Betas() as $beta)
<p>Beta: <br />{{ $beta }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems linking view and controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25448157/problems-linking-view-and-controller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you call the *with* method, try to set the $alpha variable first:

```
public function display($alpha_id)
{
    $alpha = $this->alphaRepository->findBy($alpha_id);
    return View::make('alpha.show')->with('alpha',$alpha);
}
```

Comment: If you use that code you get a syntax error on the 'alpha' => $alpha.

Comment: Updated the answer, use *with('alpha',$alpha);* instead of *=>*